# How to set interrupt with serial on linux?

Tags: c, linux, unix, serial-port, posix

I want to set interrupt for serial port on linux,so I do it by signal.And the handler of signal hava worded,but I don't know how to get the number of character.Specifically I am not sure the third parameter in read() function when the handler is called by system.So,I need a solution that knows the amount of serial data.

Thanks you all.

PS：My English is not good,so the above may not be clearly expressed

```
void serialHandler(int sig)
{
    read(fd,buffer,I don't know);
}
```

Comment: The third parameter depends on the amount of data you expect and the size of the buffer you pass to `read()` (whatever is less)

Comment: It sounds like you need `aio_read`, which sets up the read with a buffer and specified size limit, and sends you a signal when the read is complete.  Once that comes, `aio_return` tells you how many bytes were actually transferred.

Comment: Alternatively set the file descriptor to non-blocking. Then read will return with however many character are present.

Answer (score 1):

*Specifically I am not sure the third parameter in read() function when the handler is called by system*

*[read()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html)* is described fully here, and includes the following example:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
...
char buf[20];
size_t nbytes;
ssize_t bytes_read;
int fd;
...
nbytes = sizeof(buf);
bytes_read = read(fd, buf, nbytes);
```

It is common to use a loop construct (for example around similar code to that shown above) while testing the output of *read* for an exit criteria.  In the above implementation (not looped) `bytes_read` contains the number of bytes successfully read, excluding any carriage return characters removed. If a read error or end-of-file ( `EOF` ) is encountered, the returned value can be less than that specified in the number_ofBytes parameter. If an error occurs, read returns 0 and sets `errno` to a nonzero value.

Note: As mentioned in the comments, using `read()` in conjunction with a serial port most likely precludes it will ever see an `EOF` condition.

Also to expound on the comment about *[using timeouts with read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070731/linux-serial-port-blocking-read-with-timeout)*, and how to *[implement a timeout for the read function itself using the select()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917881/how-to-implement-a-timeout-in-read-function-call)* function.

There is more *[information here](https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html#2_5_4)* to help with creating algorithms to read from port.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning however, that a read on a serial port usually never returns EOF. Length and end of data has to be determined by some sort of framing protocol.

Comment: Emmmm,It seems that my statement has a problem.I mean that ,for example,three bytes came from the serial port,but I don't know it's three,if I set the third parameter to one,there will be two bytes lost.

Comment: @buyuer The bytes are not lost, you can read them in in a subsequent call to `read()`.

Comment: @Ctx-Thank you very much ,I seem got it,and I know what I should do.Thank you again.