# How to move a file in C++ after reading it via send?

Tags: c++, file

Well, I've see this question about my problem and the solution seems to be good.
[Send and Receive a file in socket programming in Linux with C/C++ (GCC/G++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014033/send-and-recive-file-in-socket-programming-in-linux-with-c-c-gcc)

Well. My goal is to receive a txt file and after receiving it, I want to store it into a path.
I have now a question:
when I receive the bytes through the recv function, how can I merge all bytes into a txt file?

Answer (score 1):

I think [std::ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Or `fopen`/`fwrite`, which continue to work just fine in C++ and tend to be considerably faster.

Comment: @BenVoigt: If you like C files, check out my [wrapper](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio) :-)