# Writing a full buffer using write() system call

Tags: c, sockets, buffer

I want to write a buffer filled with `BUFF_SIZE` bytes over a TCP socket using the [write system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write):

```
#include <unistd.h>
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) states that

> write() writes *up to count* bytes from the buffer pointed buf to the file referred to by the file descriptor fd.

Of course, the number of *actual* bytes written can be detected by the return value.  However, if I want to ensure that my whole buffer of bytes gets sent over the connection, what would be a good way to do this?  So far, I was thinking:

```
while ( (ch = fgetc(pipe) ) != EOF )
{
    buff[ 0 ] = ch;
    bytes_in_buff++;

    // fill a buffer's worth of data from the pipe
    for (int i = 1; i < BUFF_SIZE; ++i, ++bytes_in_buff)
    {
        if ( (ch = fgetc(pipe) ) == EOF)
            break;

        buff[ i ] = ch;
    }

    // write that buffer to the pipe
    int bytes_sent = 0;
    while (bytes_sent < BUFF_SIZE)
    {
        bytes_sent = write(fd, buff, bytes_in_buff);
    }
}
```

But of course, some redundant bytes will be sent if I continue to send the entire buffer each time `bytes_sent < BUFF_SIZE` .

Answer (score 2):

If `write()` returns less than `BUFF_SIZE` your suggested loop will never terminate; and you need to check for errors.

You need something like this:

```
while (bytes_in_buff > 0)
{
    bytes_sent = write(fd, buff, bytes_in_buff);
    if (bytes_sent < 0)
    {
        perror("write");  // or whatever
        break;
    }
    buff += bytes_sent;
    bytes_in_buff -= bytes_sent;
}
```

*However* this issue was discussed *in extenso* on news:comp.protocols.tcp-ip some years ago, which is the place where TCP/IP implementators hang out, and it was agreed there that, in blocking mode, both `write()` and `send()` must send the entire buffer before returning.

Comment: Is your last paragraph true when the system call is blocked and then interrupted? Will the implementation of the system call always automatically restart the I/O if interrupted?

Comment: @jxh I'm sorry I cannot recall the discussion in that level of detail, but it seems to me that it shouldn't restart. How it advises both an interrupt and the number of bytes transferred before the interrupt has always been a mystery to me.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following function which loops around `write()` until `s` bytes from `b` had been written or a fatal error had occurred:

```
int writen(const int sd, const char * b, const size_t s, const int retry_on_interrupt)
{
  size_t n = s;
  while (0 < n)
  {
    ssize_t result = write(sd, b, n);
    if (-1 == result)
    {
      if ((retry_on_interrupt && (errno == EINTR)) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK) || (errno == EAGAIN))
      {
        continue;
      }
      else
      {
        break;
      }
    }

    n -= result;
    b += result;
  }

  return (0 < n) ?-1 :0;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
int retry_on_interrupt = ... /* {0|1} depending on wether a signal reception shall abort the write operation or not. */
int result = writen(fd, buff, sizeof(buf), retry_on_interrupt)
if (-1 == result)
{
  perror("writen()");
}
```

Comment: Would converting to `FILE*` with `fdopen` and then using `fwrite` be enough?

Comment: @CiroSantilli华涌低端人口六四事件法轮功: This would very well be worth a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the parameters you give to write to account for the data you've already sent. So something like this:

```
int bytes_sent = 0;
int remaining = BUFF_SIZE;
while (remaining) 
{
  bytes_sent = write(fd, buff, remaining);
  remaining -= bytes_sent;
  buff += bytes_sent;
}
```