# C Socket file transfer between server & client

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to figure out how to send a file from my server to the client using C. I'm very new at C, so not sure entirely how wrong I have it:

Snippet server:

```
while (1) { 
    len = sizeof(clientAddr); 
    sock = accept(serverSock, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &len);
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    while(!feof(file)) {
        int flen = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file);
        int sz = 0;
          while (sz < flen) {
            int sent = send(sock, &buffer[sz], flen-sz, 0);
            sz += sent;
          }
        printf("Sent file!");
     }
    fclose(file);
    close(sock);
}
```

Snippet from Client

```
int status = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&Address, sizeof(Address));

int flen;
file = fopen(filename, "wb");
while(flen = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) > 0) {
    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    fwrite(buffer,1, flen, file);
}
```

Basically, I'm getting an error of "Segmentation Fault (core dump)" from the server. Is there any guide on trying to do this? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should probably be checking that `file` is non-null before trying to use it.  Also, this is a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger to see exactly where and why you're getting the segmentation fault.

Comment: How is `buffer` defined?

Comment: Your while statement should have another pair of parentheses. You are setting `flen` to the result of the comparison `recv(...) > 0)`. Not apparently what you intended. You probably want `while ((flen = recv(...)) > 0) {` which sets `flen` to the return value of `recv` and compares that with 0. (This doesn't explain your segmentation fault as far as I can tell.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send and Receive a file in socket programming in Linux with C/C++ (GCC/G++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014033/send-and-receive-a-file-in-socket-programming-in-linux-with-c-c-gcc-g)